# Choosing the right type of plot for my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, data-visualization, pandas, matplotlib

I have been confused because I don't know which type of plot I must choose. I have a data frame with two columns suppose the first one is the id of a person and the second one the number of houses this person has. I just only want to know which type of plot I need to use.

According to my problem:

I will rank the owners on a number of houses basis. (OK till now) So, the first owner will be the one that owns the largest number of houses (e.g. 14), the second owner will be the one with the second largest number of listings, etc.

If there is a number of owners with the same number of houses, just add them in sequence. For instance, if there are 10 owners with one listing each, add them in the ranking with any order between them.

That is, a point $(x,y)$ will mean that the $x$ -th highest owner host has $y$ listings.

Any advise?

Comment: Any graph can answer only some sort of questions? Which is your question?

Comment: @rapaio which type of graph you would use to draw this plot? scatter, line? i 've been confused.. I want only to draw the plot nothing else ...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a bar chart, which should be pretty straightforward in matplotlib by using `matplotlib.pyplot.bar()`

In case you'd like to do some extra reading, here is a [tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart/) and here is the matplotlib bar chart [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, choice of a plot depends on a lot of factors including what you are trying to learn.

Reading the description you provide, it sounds like a simple histogram is a good start.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html

I also recommend sorting by the number of houses first:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html